# Does Dapr Workflow support mixed programming languages?

Tags: workflow, dapr

I understand that I can implement services in Dapr by using multiple programming languages. This question is specifically about [Dapr Workflow](https://docs.dapr.io/developing-applications/building-blocks/workflow/). In all the [examples](https://docs.dapr.io/developing-applications/building-blocks/workflow/workflow-overview/#quickstarts-and-tutorials), activities and workflows are defined in a single application, written in one programming language.

Specifically, is it possible to define a workflow in one Dapr application that references either an activity or another workflow that is defined in a different Dapr application, if those applications are written in different programming languages?